# AngularJS directive binding issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created an AngularJS directive on one of the pages and it's not rendering. I don't get any errors either. Following is the directive template and directive binding code. Appreciate if someone can help.

directive.js

```
var cardCollapsiblePanelModule = angular.module('cardCollapsiblePanelModule',[]);
cardCollapsiblePanelModule.directive('cardCollapsiblePanel', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'scripts/virtualserver/virtualserverfeatures/monitoringprobes/views/directive-      templates/monitoring-probe-card-collapsible-panel-template.html',
        scope: {
            cardName: '@cardName'
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            // update dependent scope.
        },
        link: function (scope, $element, $attrs) {}

    }
});
```

directive HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title clearfix" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
    <div class="pull-left">{{ cardName }}</div>
    <div class="pull-right" ><span class="iconSmall iconExpand"></span></div>
</h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body">
 <!-- load the capture card settings directive here -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

directive is being used as follows:

```
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <!-- accordion directive for collapsible panel -->
        <div card-collapsible-panel card-index="{{$index}}" ng-repeat="card in monitoringProbeCards">
        </div>
    </div>
```

My objective is to bind the headers of collapsible panels with the card name through the directive. Can someone point out what's wrong with the code?

My REST service response is as follows:

```
[{"id":1,"cardName":"Card 0 : PIST-16-TDM-PCI-Basic-32 - SN:    GPER190201064","interfaceType":"TDM","probeServerId":2},{"id":2,"cardName":"Card 1 : PIST-16-TDM-PCI-Basic-32 - SN:   GPER190201065","interfaceType":"TDM","probeServerId":2}]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not rendering"? The DOM doesn't change at all? I take it Angular has bootstraped?

Comment: yes, it's bootstrapped. What I mean is, the directive doesn't get data-bound.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <!-- accordion directive for collapsible panel -->
    <div ng-repeat="card in monitoringProbeCards">
       <div card-collapsible-panel="{{$index}}"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add card-name to the directive Div:

```
<div card-collapsible-panel card-index="{{$index}}" ng-repeat="card in monitoringProbeCards" card-name="{{card.cardName}}" >
```

Binding to `{{cardName}}` from the directive HTML, binds to the `cardName` field on the isolated scope which in turn via the `@` sign followed by `cardName` binds to the `card-name` attribute on the directive using one-way data binding which means that the value of that attribute needs to be evaluated by Angular, hence the `{{card.cardName}}`.